# Can we have nested HTML form in Django framework?

Tags: python, html, django

```
<form action="#" method ="POST>
    <input …>
    <input …>
        <form action ="#" method="POST>
             <input …>
             <input …>
             <button type = "submit" name = "inner">..
        </form>
    <button type = "submit" name = "outer">..
</form>
```

Can we use such nested form to submit to a single function in `views.py`?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwumR.png)

The first form searches for a record in a CSV. Then next form saves the information with additional data on click of "Save".

Comment: What are you attempting to do?

Comment: I want values returned by the first form to be used by another form along with some data from the first form.

Comment: So you want to show one form and then show another form based on the data from the first form?

Comment: Yes. Some data from the previous form.